# How to change Gmail's password programmatically?

Tags: php, authentication, passwords, gmail

I came across this issue recently where I needed to change a Gmail's account password programmatically and am still thinking about the ideal approach.

Basically by providing Gmail's current username/password my application would then authenticate and request the password to be changed to a new one provided and return success.

CURL seems to be the obvious choice as I usually work with PHP, but I have also been looking into other possibilities like [libgmailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gmail-lite/), [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/), or [scRUBYt!](http://scrubyt.org/) (although not sure you can post with the this).

- How would you approach this task?
- Are there any other already made
  tools to simplify this task?
- Is it even feasible?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to change this programmatically.

Comment: Um, if your app can do this, so can somebody else's app.

Comment: @DOK not sure what you mean? I specifically stated that the current credentials are provided.

Comment: @Lazarus It would be an option for clients within a webservice not yet live.

Comment: If you are using Google to authenticate the web service users then they should change their password on Google not on your app.

Comment: @Lazarus No, Google is not being used to authenticate to the app. Changing/resetting the password via the app is part of the app's services/offers.

Comment: What else is your web service doing for them? This seems like a really odd web service to offer.

Comment: @Lazarus Google was also "a really odd web service" when it launched...

Comment: @mr-euro: Not sure what you mean, Google wasn't the first directory/search-engine and didn't offer any kind of API in the beginning from what I recall, I could be wrong on the last piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reliable solution for this. If you use curl - that's ok, but you will have tu support the application forever.

Also, you will need to handle captcha ;-)

Anything except changin password is possible via API, but not this, AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, I have been looking through the various Google APIs documentation and found nothing matching specifically my task. Does changing password also requires CAPTCHA? I do not use Gmail personally so can not test it right now.

Comment: I don't remember too, but even if it does - you can show captcha to the user in your app, it's all possible via CURL.