# Is there any way of changing gmail password programmatically using java?

Tags: java, google-api

Is there any way of changing gmail password programmatically using java?

Comment: There is if you're using Google Apps - there's a provisioning API, but you'll need to be a little more specific.

Comment: Not sure if it's still the case but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891345/how-to-change-gmails-password-programmatically

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562#44562) Also, StackOverflow isn't a forum; if you have a new question, please ask a new question. If you want to include more information in your question, please [edit it](). If you want to interact with one of the people who has answered, you can leave them a comment.

Comment: It is not related with Gmail. You should look for **Google Accounts**  API.

Answer (score 2):

The google provisioning API [guide](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_reference.html#User_Account_URL_Table) has updateUser method which takes a UserEntry object. You can use it to update the password I suppose, you will have to try it out. Check the [javadocs](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/) for definition of UserEntry

Answer (score 0):

I would have been very surprised if you could, and it doesn't look like it.

This page shows you the list of settings you can change in the Google Apps "Email Settings API", and change-password isn't there.

http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_settings/developers_guide_protocol.html#GA_email_settings_api_ops

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I think yes. You can record all operation with web pages by Selenium, test if all ok, and after export to java code - only problem can arise if Google will use CAPCHA

Answer (score 0):

Uh, just use an http client to post this web page: https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/EditPasswd.  Use http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/ or something similar.  You'll need to keep track of cookies properly, so google thinks you are logged in when you load the page.  But yeah, obviously it is possible.  If your browser can do it, you can do it programmatically through sending http requests.  If you want to be double careful, you can use something like [tamperdata](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) in firefox to sniff exactly what your browser sends when you request a password change, so you don't miss any silent fields or whatnot.

Comment: is that url always remains same?? or is it dynamic???
if it is static then how could i get EditPassword pragmatically??

Comment: It isn't guaranteed to stay the same but there's no reason to think it will if it hasn't in almost two years.  Look up http clients like the apache httpclient as I mentioned in my post if you want to access it programattically

Answer (score 0):

Using [Google Provisioning API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#updating_a_user_account), to change the password, you have to set it to [login](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/appsforyourdomain/Login) attribute of UserEntry object:

```
import sample.appsforyourdomain.AppsForYourDomainClient;
...
AppsForYourDomainClient client = new AppsForYourDomainClient(email, password, domain);
UserEntry user = client.retrieveUser("username");
user.getLogin().setPassword("newpassword");
client.updateUser("username", user);
```